# is there any way to stop part of process without disturbing whole process?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which iterates on customer ids and I have process function which process those customer in the same for loop.

Scenario:-

while executing for loop, if the repetitive customer is found then we should check if the old process of customer is finished or not. if finished then we must wait.

here I don't want to halt my whole for loop execution as other customers having different ids can be processed.

so is there any way using that I can stop only part of process that is waiting for particular customer while executing others using same for loop.

example

```
for(customer:customers)
{
 if(customer.isRepeated())
 {
  if(customer.inProcess())
   {
    wait();
   }
 }
 process(customer);

}
```

Comment: Are these `process` calls running in separate threads? Separate JVM instances? If it's all one thread, then only one thing can happen on that thread at a time.

Comment: This sounds like a poor design. You should really include some actual code too. Have you found a problem, or are you trying to solve a problem you expect to have?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo no its running on same thread. in same JVM instance

Comment: Sounds and looks like you are not using multiple threads. Solution would be to create a new thread for each customer

Comment: If `process` runs in the same thread, it won't return until it finishes with the current customer. So how would your loop find the same customer again `inProcess()`?

Comment: You can use an `ExecutorService`, and submit a task for each customer, and keeping the `Future` returned by the `submit` in a `Map` where the keys are customer IDs.

Comment: `if finished then we must wait.` did you mean if NOT finished then we must wait?

Comment: @MauricePerry if not finished then wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem you've described, the multithreaded approach in the other answer is probably ideal. But if you want to keep it single-threaded and defer processing for customers that aren't ready yet while processing customers that are ready, then this might work.

Here, we create another list of `waitingCustomers`, which is a list of the customers that we would have called `.wait()` on. Instead of doing that, when we reach a customer who needs to wait, we put it in the `waitingCustomers` list. And then we repeat the entire block of code until the `waitingCustomers` list is empty.

```
List<Customer> waitingCustomers = customers;
do {
    List<Customer> toProcess = waitingCustomers;
    waitingCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(customer : toProcess) {
        if(customer.isRepeated() && customer.inProcess()) {
            waitingCustomers.add(customer);
        } else {
            process(customer);
        }
    }
} while (waitingCustomers.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html).

```
Deque<Customer> toProcess;
//inialize and populate the queue
while( toProcess.size() > 0){
    //take the front
    Customer c = toProcess.remove();
    if( c.inProcess() ){
        //put it back at the tail.
        toProcess.offer(c);
        continue;
    }
    //operate on it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use kind of Asynchronous programming for this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Do whatever
    }
}).start();
```